# Discrete Morse function from smooth one

Tags: discrete-geometry, morse-theory, at.algebraic-topology, gt.geometric-topology

Suppose I have a smooth manifold $M$ and a smooth Morse function $f$ on $M$.  Is there a standard way to replace $M$ with a cell complex and $f$ with a discrete Morse function such the resulting homology (via discrete Morse theory) is the same as that of $M$?

My question is motivated by a situation where I know the critical points of $f$, but not how they are connected by gradient flow lines.  So I am interested in a solution which doesn't depend on that information.  I imagine something like the following: Triangulate so that every critical point of $f$ lies on a simplex of the appropriate dimension, then define a discrete vector field by [some process].  This vector field has no nontrivial closed paths [for some reason].  By [some observation], the resulting homology is isomorphic to that of $M$.

For an expert in Morse theory, does this even sound plausible?  Are there "well-known" methods or results which would fill in the gaps?  Even better, does such a result exist somewhere already?

---

UPDATE:  Mainly I am interested in computing the homology of $M$ without having complete information about the gradient flow of $f$.  In particular, I have a specific smooth function on $\mathbb{R}^9$ coming from some data analysis.  I would like to find the homology of the region $M = $ { $ f \le C $ }.  I have a strategy for finding the critical points of $f$, but determining how they are connected by flow lines seems problematic.  Converting to a discrete problem would, I hope, provide a way around this.

I'm also not worried about pathologies: $f$ has finitely many critical points, and $M$ is compact.

---

UPDATE 2:  Thanks for the comments everyone!  I will now go to think some more.

Comment: Niles: You should specify which form of discrete Morse theory you are interested in, since there are at least 2: Bestvina-Brady's and Forman's. 

Comment: Could you perhaps tell us something about what you'd like to use the output discrete Morse function for, what you'd like to do with it?  It might help people find a more useful answer for you. 

Comment: Oh, I wasn't aware of Bestvina-Brady -- thanks for the pointer.  I was thinking of Forman, but a cursory look indicates that Bestvina-Brady may work for me.

Comment: If I understand what you are asking, this sounds like a situation where Forman's discrete Morse theory would not have any advantage over traditional Morse theory.

Comment: I also think you'll need more than discrete Morse theory.  So from the sounds of it you know the groups in your chain complex, just not the connecting maps.   If your chain complex isn't too large, frequently one can compute the homology by slowly building-up the level-sets of $f$, one critical point at a time.  If you wanted to try and get some brute-force insight via computation you might want to consider intersecting $C$ with a regular lattice, and sending that lattice to JavaPLEX for it to compute the homology of that, then check to see if your answer is stable under subdivision. 

Comment: Hmmm... @Patricia Hersh and @Ryan Budney, are you saying that the information contained in Forman's discrete Morse complex is equivalent to that of the smooth Morse complex, and therefore I can't hope to compute the former without knowing the latter?

Comment: If you want to use discrete Morse theory as a computational tool you'll have to triangulate your domain appropriately to adapt it to your Morse function.  The problem is there aren't (to my knowledge) any really sophisticated algorithms for this, so you'll get a huge triangulation manageable only with software.  Off the top of my head I don't know any robust, rigorous software that can deal with discrete Morse functions on "large" triangulations.  Googling around a bit I don't find anything but perhaps I don't know what to look for. 

Comment: Actually, what Liviu writes sounds very reasonable to me. I had been focusing on your saying you had limited knowledge of the flow and so had thought you'd still have trouble finding a discrete Morse function with your desired critical cells and just be creating artificial, extra work for yourself.  

Comment: Oh, my "strategy" for finding critical points of $f$ consists of some software I'm working on.  I think (exploiting some details of $f$), that the triangulation is manageable (with software).  The problem of determining the boundary maps in the discrete Morse complex then looks like a problem about paths on a graph.  As long as the triangulation doesn't get out of control, existing algorithms should be able to handle that.

Comment: Here is a special case of your question which is already nontrivial: is the sublevel set $\{f\leq c\}$ connected?

Comment: My paper "On optimizing discrete Morse functions" has a result on how to deduce information about cell incidences among critical cells from the data from a larger triangulation and a discrete Morse function having these as its critical cells.  If you really have software to do that, maybe the paper will help a little bit too.

Comment: Maybe the paper of Bruno Benedetti found at

http://arxiv.org/pdf/1010.0548v4.pdf

would be of interest to you.

Comment: See also the recent survey , also by Benedetti http://arxiv.org/abs/1212.0885

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is a rapidly developing area, and there are many short-cuts if all you want to do is compute the homology of sub-level sets of $f$. To answer your main question, as Liviu has already mentioned: **there is no standard way**. However, you should be able to compute the homology you desire as follows.

My impression is that you have three jobs, in chronological order:

1. Construct a simplicial complex $X_M$ homologically faithful to $M$.
2. Construct a discrete Morse function $\mu:X_M \to \mathbb{R}$ which approximates $f$, and
3. Compute homology of everything in sight.

First, the easiest way to build a simplicial approximation if you know your $M$ is to embed it in some suitable $\mathbb{R}^n$ and sample the hell out of it. Since you are working on data analysis, this should not be too drastic a step. Given a point sample $P$ coming from a submanifold of Euclidean space, for each radius $\epsilon$ you can construct a Cech complex of radius $\epsilon$ around $P$. Precise bounds on how many points $P$ should have and how large $\epsilon$ can be in order for the Cech complex to recover the homology of $M$ with high confidence are available in the work of Niyogi, Smale and Weinberger [here](http://people.cs.uchicago.edu/~niyogi/papersps/NiySmaWeiHom.pdf) in the case when $P$ is uniformly sampled. These bounds are in terms of the injectivity radius of the embedding of $M$ into Euclidean space, and of course once these bounds are satisfied it doesn't hurt to add your known critical points to $P$. You have your homologically faithful Cech complex $X_M$.

Next, for 2, you can easily infer a discrete Morse function on an entire simplicial complex just from knowing its values on the vertices using the [work](http://ftp4.de.freesbie.org/pub/misc/EMIS/journals/EM/expmath/volumes/14/14.4/King.pdf) of King, Knudson and Mramor. You may be required to perturb $f$ slightly so that its restriction to $P$ is injective, but this is easy and generically true. You have $\mu$!

And finally, I have written [software](http://www.math.rutgers.edu/~vidit/perseus.html) to handle 3 if you already have a $\mu:X_M \to \mathbb{R}$: you can input a filtered simplicial complex and compute not just homology at each sub-level set of $\mu$ but the persistent homology across all level-sets in the case of field coefficients. Meaning, instead of just knowing the homology of the subcomplexes $X_M^c$ consisting of all simplices with $\mu$-value less than or equal to $c$, you also recover the morphism on homology groups induced by including $X_M^c$ into $X_M^d$ whenever $c \leq d$.

All the best with your computations.

Comment: Thanks!  These are indeed useful, although the Niyogi-Smale-Weinberger strategy pushes the question to estimating tau (e.g. via the second fundamental form) and to determining a uniform distribution on M.  Also, "sampling the hell out of it" is problematic as the ambient dimension grows.  It looks reasonable to give a local version of NSW, so that the sampling density doesn't have to be uniform over M.  I don't suppose anyone has done this, have they?

Comment: Niles: no one has done this yet, at least no one that I know of.

Answer (score 6):

World seems to be small. I have tried the approach you outlined with a  former student of mine and we got stuck  in the simplest  case, the height function on a torus.The saddle point  was (and is) a serious headache.

Let me mention   our  strategy  maybe you get lucky.  In a recent [paper](http://www.nd.edu/%7Elnicolae/tameflow.pdf)  I showed that given any  triangulated  space together with a Morse-Forman  function on it, there exists a genuine flow  on this space with the following properties

1. The critical points are the exactly barycenters of all the faces.
2. The Conley index of the barycenter of a critical face is a sphere of the same dimension  as the face.
3. The  Conley index of the barycenter of a non-critical face is  homotopically trivial

The flows are easily  described and visualized and they belong to a class of flows I called tame. There  examples of tame flows  beyond the class generated by a Morse-Forman   function and they are as well behaved.  To get such flows on a triagulated space it suffices to label the vertices. The flow runs from the higher label to the lower label.  We thought that using the Morse function  for labeling would do the trick.

Given a Morse function on a manifold one could envisage constructing such a flow  by choosing   a sufficiently fine triangulation  and trying to guess  how the gradient flow would behave on each face. Things  get hairy  near the critical points.   However I still believe this approach has legs.

As for associating a Morse-Forman function to a  Morse function there are some recent results in this direction [arXiv: 1010.0548](https://arxiv.org/abs/1010.0548)  or  [arXiv: 0803.2616](https://arxiv.org/abs/0803.2616).

**Remark.**   This in reply to your new question. There are as many  stationary points as faces. The barycenter of *each* face is a stationary point. However, only few of these stationary points have *nontrivial*   Conley index. I will refer to the other stationary points as *ghosts*, and the level sets containing ghosts as *ghost levels*.

The Conley index of a barycenter  of a face is nontrivial if and only if that face is critical in the sense  of Forman. In my paper mentioned in my answer I describe a  general process (flip-flop) that generalizes the  process of handle attachment.  Crossing  a ghost level  does not change the homotopy type of the sublevel set.

The process of crossing of ghost level    does not even change the *simple homotopy* type.    If $\lbrace f=c\rbrace$ is a ghost level, then $\lbrace f\leq c+\varepsilon\rbrace$ is     simple homotopic to the space obtained  from $\lbrace f\leq c-\varepsilon\rbrace$ by attaching a cone over a contractibe subset $B\subset \lbrace f=c-\varepsilon\rbrace$.

The space $\lbrace f\leq c+\varepsilon \rbrace$ is $PL$ homeomorphic  to the space obtained  from $\lbrace f\leq c-\varepsilon\rbrace$  by a flip-flop which is essentially a  blowdown followed by a blowup along  clearly  defined loci.

Comment: Thanks!  These look promising.  Do you think one could finish your program with an assumption that nothing too wild happens near critical points -- maybe with some bounds on second or third derivatives of $f$?

Comment: The  problem you have in mind  in its complete generality, and no additional assumption on $f$  seems difficult. Homology  is after all  a global object and at some point you need to extract some global information from somewhere.

Comment: In your first point, do you mean to say that the critical points of the genuine flow are barycenters of the *critical* faces, or all faces?

Comment: I'll reply  on my post since I do not have enough space on the comment section.